# Python 3.7 cannot use DOCPLEX

Tags: python, docplex

I have coded a mathematical model and want to solve it using DOCPLEX module. My interpreter is Python 3.7. However, after doing a lot of effort, I will face the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 290, in get_cplex_module
    import cplex  #@UnresolvedImport
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\cplex\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .aborter import Aborter
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\cplex\aborter.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._internal import _procedural as _proc
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\cplex\_internal\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import _list_array_utils
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\cplex\_internal\_list_array_utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _pycplex as CPX
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\cplex\_internal\_pycplex.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _pycplex_platform
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\cplex\_internal\_pycplex_platform.py", line 22, in <module>
    from cplex._internal.py37_cplex2010 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cplex._internal.py37_cplex2010'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/EPC _LTC.py", line 11, in <module>
    mdl = Model("LTC")
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\model.py", line 398, in __init__
    self._environment = self._make_environment()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\model.py", line 174, in _make_environment
    env = Environment.get_default_env()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 427, in get_default_env
    Environment._default_env = Environment.make_new_configured_env()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 422, in make_new_configured_env
    return Environment(start_auto_configure=True)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.auto_configure(logger=logger)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 220, in auto_configure
    self.check_cplex(logger=logger)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 328, in check_cplex
    cplex = self.get_cplex_module(logger=logger)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 314, in get_cplex_module
    cplex = load_cplex_from_cos_root(loc) if loc else None
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 286, in load_cplex_from_cos_root
    return load_cplex(full_path, version=version)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\environment.py", line 261, in load_cplex
    raise FileNotFoundError("Could not load module from %s" % module_location)
FileNotFoundError: Could not load module from C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64\cplex;\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64\cplex\__init__.py
```

I have already run the following codes in my Pycharm's terminal:

```
cd C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\python
python setup.py install
```

or

```
cd C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\python
python setup.py install --home C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\cplex
```

Finally, I also set the path variables of my own username to something like below:

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio129\cplex\python\3.6\x64_win64" and
"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio129\cplex\bin\x64_win64\cplex.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I upgraded to python 3.8 and solved the issue

or you can use this:

```
pip install docplex==2.15.194
```

Comment: I thought docplex is incompatible with Python 3.8. Anyway, I just upgraded to this newer version and still, the same problem exists.

Comment: "pip install docplex==2.15.194" worked!! Many thanks.

Comment: Again, I face another error "docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexException: CPLEX runtime not found: please install CPLEX or solve this model on DOcplexcloud"

Comment: From the stack I see, there seems to be a mixup between Python 3.8 and 3.7. The root content of the Python/cplex layer should be consistent with the interpreter version. The one  I mentioned was for 3.7. If using 3.8 you have to change it .

Comment: In addition, I see you have installed Python module "cplex". If you have COS installed this is not necessary, on the contrary this might be confusing. You should update the "docplex" package from pypi to the latest 2.20 release, and make it aware of your COS install via content root in Pycharm. The cplex module contains a limited version of CPLEX (1000 vars, 1000 constraints) that you dont need if you have COS.

Comment: To summarize: 1. uninstall "cplex", 2. update "docplex" to 2.20, 3. add content root path of COS to Pycharm( with path consistent with Pythonversion), 4. try a bare "import cplex" in Pycharm console

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `python setup.py install` does not guaranty that the python interpreter you are using is the same as your virtual env.

You need to activate your env before you run the install script.
Please open a Terminal then run:

```
C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\activate
```

Then you can

```
cd C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python
pip install .
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just did what you said, but still the same error exists. Please see the below image. Please help me as I have stopped working on my thesis project because of this issue.

https://ibb.co/NCHKn1n

Answer (score 1):

Docplex has a `check_list.py` script, which helps diagnose presence and location of cplex versions. In a terminal where Python is present, type

```
$ python -m docplex.mp.check_list
```

The answer looks like:

```
* system is: Windows 64bit
* Python version 3.7.8, located at: C:\python\anaconda2020.02\envs\docplex37\python.exe
* docplex is present, version is 2.20.204
* CPLEX library is present, version is 12.10.0.0, located at: C:\OPTIM\cplex_distrib\cplex1210R0\python\3.7\x64_win64
* pandas is present, version is 1.1.4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you said, and I got something like the below image. What should be the problem? https://ibb.co/KLVpVsx

Answer (score 1):

From the check list output you posted, I can see that you installed cos201.
Docplex need the Python/Cplex interface located inside cos, in your case:

```
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x64_win64
```

This path should be added as a `content root` in your Pycharm project (File/Settings/Project Structure -> add content root

To check this, open a Python console tab in Pycharm, and try

```
import cplex
```

Once you add the right path , this should work.
You can then run the check list from within the console:

```
from docplex.mp.check_list import run_docplex_check_list
run_docplex_check_list()
```

Once this works, your program should solve OK inside Pycharm.
This said, I see your version of docplex is 2.15, which is older than CPLEX 20.1. You should update DOcplex to the latest version, which is compatible with CPLEX 20.1.

Comment: Thank you so so much, but the problem still exists. As per your suggestion, I tried to upgrade the docplex module using "pip install --ignore-installed -U docplex"; Please see that I have upgraded to the latest version: https://ibb.co/7yNd4bL. Then, I added the aforementioned content root like here: https://ibb.co/ZSryVk4. However, when I run "import cplex" in PyCharm's console, I face this error: https://ibb.co/6N1TXW3

Comment: After doing these steps: https://ibb.co/Yt9SyYW, I'm facing a similar error: https://ibb.co/nw5gkv6. Thanks for your attention.